# laravel whereHas results weird

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

product model

```
    public function country() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ProductCountry', 'product_id', 'id');
    }
```

the controller

```
$product = Product::where('mall_' . $this->mall_id, '=', 1)
    ->whereHas('country', function ($i) use ($me) {
        return $i->where('country_id', $me->country_id);
    })
    ->find($key);
```

the raw SQL:

```
select * from `product` where `mall_3` = '1' and exists (select * from `product_country` where `product_country`.`product_id` = `product`.`id` and `country_id` = '109') and `product`.`id` = '3' and `product`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1
```

above SQL return no results(when the product id = 3

below SQL return the correct result(when the product id = 6)

```
select * from `product` where `mall_3` = '1' and exists (select * from `product_country` where `product_country`.`product_id` = `product`.`id` and `country_id` = '109') and `product`.`id` = '6' and `product`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1
```

have no idea, the query look like no problem

previous project i got this issues too, at the end i use find and loop once more instead of using whereHas, but this time i encounter this problem again and try to find out why but few hours wasted, still no clue, below is a workaround(ignoring the bugs?)

```
$products = array();
foreach ($request->get('quantity') as $key => $var) {
    if ($var > 0) {
        $product = Product::with(['country'])->where('mall_' . $this->mall_id, '=', 1)
                    ->find($key);

        foreach ($product->country as $c) {
            if ($c->country_id == $me->country_id && !isset($products[$product->id])) {
                //Do something here...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you tried joining the tables instead of going for exists check?

Comment: not yet try joining, but would like to know what happend with this exists check query, looks ok but not working, is really weird/bug

Comment: why are you using `find()` after constructing the query?

Comment: i use find because want to find exact product, and i use whereHas together because i want the query do VALIDATION too, making sure no product to be order from another country, i think this way will prevent user to inspect element editing the product id in the order form

Comment: hi there, i think you would get great use out of laravel collection methods (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#available-methods). Specifically 'map' and 'filter' methods.

Comment: i know there is many alternative way, i also provided 1, i just curious why is the error happend and what is the reason, to improve

Comment: I've tried and it's just fine

Answer (score 4):

i created the tables mentioned above (giving exactly same relations, table names, model names) and tried your code (by giving hard coded values)

```
public function try1(){
    $me = 109;
    $key = 3;
    $product = Product::where('mall_3' , '=', 1)
        ->whereHas('country', function ($i) use ($me) {
            return $i->where('country_id', $me);
        })

        ->find($key);

    return $product;
}

public function try2(){
    $me = 109;
    $key = 6;
    $product = Product::where('mall_3' , '=', 1)
        ->whereHas('country', function ($i) use ($me) {
            return $i->where('country_id', $me);
        })

        ->find($key);

    return $product;
}
```

but got the perfect results

```
 {"id":3,"mall_1":1,"mall_2":1,"mall_3":1}
```

and

```
{"id":6,"mall_1":1,"mall_2":1,"mall_3":1}
```

pls check if everything is fine with your database, check if every primary key and foreign keys are created as "integer". And check "collation" of db well as tables.

Comment: then its weird, i just double check, confirmed `product_country`.`product_id` is UNSIGNED INTEGER(10), i also checked both `product_country` and `product` TABLE is same collation utf8_unicode_ci

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't seem Laravel-related (since you still get no results when running the query directly with MyAdmin).

```sql
select * from `product`
where true
-- and `mall_3` = '1'
and exists (
    select * from `product_country`
    where true
    and `product_country`.`product_id` = `product`.`id`
    and `country_id` = '109'
)
and `product`.`id` = '3'
and `product`.`deleted_at` is null
limit 1
```

Run the query again, commenting each `where` condition one by one (I added a `true` first condition to easily comment out all "`and ...`" lines) to see if you spot where the problem begins.

(I did try creating both tables, and both queries return correct results, by the way.)

Comment: after checking like this, i found the `deleted_at` is not NULL for `product`.`id` = 3, what a noob mistake, thank you

Comment: @user259752 But how is that possible? On your screenshot `deleted_at` is NULL.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel u are right, i didnt check back my screenshot last time, but now my database deleted_at really null

Comment: @user259752 so now they are both null but id 3 still finds no results but id 6 does?

Comment: i tried export and import the same data to my test server, it normal/working properly, i tried to install xampp on my windows machine and import the same data, it work too, now seem like only my wampserver 64bit mysql5.7.14 not working

Answer (score 0):

First things first:

If you're using `eloquent` (find method), you can do something like:

```
Product::find($id);
```

and it returns a model of product where the id you've provided equals the primary key. Having that said, there is no need to use a `whereHas()` since it will have no effect. Instead of `find()`, you can try `get()` or `first()` for example, depending on what you're looking for.

If you want to print out your query, you can end it with `->toSql();` and it will print the query as a string (helps a lot!).

I didn't paid much attention to the objective but I'm sure if you use the

```
dd(Product::where('mall_' . $this->mall_id, '=', 1)
->whereHas('country', function ($i) use ($me) {
    return $i->where('country_id', $me->country_id);
})
->toSql());
```

You'll be able to compare what you're doing (since you know what the correct result or query should be like) and be able to figure it out.

After all, we do need to exercise to explore our mind!

Comment: i think this is bug of mysql instead of laravel, i use whereHas because  the system only show product to the user if the user in the country, think whereHas will do the VALIDATION too so wont have order out of the country, u can see the 2 query i write, doing the same but one got result and another one no result, and looking at the image i uploaded, already proof that both 2 query should have result

Comment: I've used whereHas before and didn't had any trouble, but I'll try to implement what OP wrote whenever I get home if I got the time and hopefully, I can give some updates on the matter.

I've got a little experience with laravel (about 4 months) but when it comes to Eloquent, I tend to forget the outputs they give sometimes

Answer (score 0):

try this hope it will help you,

```
 $products = array();
    foreach ($request->get('quantity') as $key => $var) {
        if ($var > 0) {
            $product = Product::where('mall_' . $this->mall_id, '=', 1)
                        ->leftjoin('product_country','product_country.product_id','=','product.id')->get();
            $products[$product->id] = ['product_id'=>$product->id,'country_id'=>$product->country_id];              
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your relationship concept in the product model from hasMany to belongsToMany.
Also update the parameters by defining the country model as first argument, intermediate table name as second argument then foreign key and primary key as 3rd and 4th arguments. **belongsToMany('App\Models\Country', 'product_country','product_id', 'country_id')**

**Product Model**

```
public function country() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Country', 'product_country','product_id', 'country_id');
}
```

Because each country may belong to many products and each product may belong to many countries.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is a little bit stale, but my team actually had a very similar issue with Laravel and the whereHas (MySQL EXISTS) on MySQL 5.7.18.

As soon as we upgraded MySQL, the same query started to return exactly as expected. I haven't yet figured out if this was a bug with 5.7.18, but I suspect it might be.